# JAWS screen reader misreads confirm dialog message. IE11

Tags: javascript, accessibility, internet-explorer-11, jaws-screen-reader

I have a confirm dialog and I want to make it accessible.
Here is my HTML:

```
<div class="confirm-dialog row-fluid">
<div class="content" role="dialog" tabindex="0" aria-labelledby="confirm-popup-header" aria-describedby="confirm-popup-subheader">
   <h2 id="confirm-popup-header">Proceed with an action</h2>
   <h4 id="confirm-popup-subheader">You are about to proceed with an action</h4>
   <div>
       <button class="btn btn-large btn-primary btn-app-secondary">Cancel</button>
       <button class="btn btn-large btn-primary btn-app-primary">Submit</button>
   </div>
</div>
```

Also somewhere in my scripts I'm setting focus to the dialog when it becomes visible:

```
$('.confirm-dialog .content').focus();
```

Then in IE11 when the dialog is opened, jaws reads it's content like that:
Enter - Proceed with an action - dialog Proceed with an action You are about to proceed with an action Cancel Submit header level two

JAWS at first reads the header, and then header and then the rest of content.
This is the problem.

Expected behavior:
Enter - Proceed with an action - dialog You are about to proceed with an action and etc.

How that can be achieved?

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the `aria-labelledby` and the `aria-describedby` from the dialog container element and you should be much better. A good best practice is also to set tabindex=-1 instead of tabindex=0 so that when you tab around in the dialog, you do not automatically go back to the container.

You may be doing this already, but you should make sure to keep the focus within the dialog using keyboard event handlers.

Comment: Thanks @unobf, but jaws behavior didn't change much after I've checked your solution. Also jaws reads buttons not like buttons)
It reads them like: No fileupload edit - TAB - Yes fileupload edit